# wait method won't wait for element to be located in DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

When I click the Next button to continue my test the page has a transition, so the password may be inputted, this transition is not allowing me to click on the password input section,  so to combat the problem I used the wait method to wait for 1s until the element is located. The error is described after code

```
const {
    Builder,
    By,
    until,
    Capabilities
} = require('selenium-webdriver');
// requiring needed modules

(async function login() {
    const pageLoad = new Capabilities().setPageLoadStrategy('normal')

//configuring the way the page loads 

    let driver = await new Builder().withCapabilities(pageLoad).forBrowser('firefox').build();
    try {

        await driver.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&rver=7.3.6963.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/&lc=1033&id=74335&aadredir=1');

//going to link

        var userName = (await driver.findElement(By.css('#i0116'))).sendKeys((USERNAME));

//finding element and typing


        (await driver.findElement(By.css('#idSIButton9'))).click();
// clicking element
        
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#i0116')),1000);
//This is where I think the error is happening
        
        var passWd = (await driver.findElement(By.css('#i0116'))).click().sendKeys(PASSWORD);
        
        (await driver.findElement(By.css('#idSIButton9'))).click();
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    } finally {
        console.log('finished')
    }

}())
```

```
{ NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: #i0116
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/name/Desktop/projects/Test/Chrome/pecPrea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/name/Desktop/projects/Test/Chrome/pecPrea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:565:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/name/Desktop/projects/Test/Chrome/pecPrea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:491:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'NoSuchElementError',
  remoteStacktrace:
   'WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:175:5\nNoSuchElementError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:387:5\nelement.find/</<@chrome://marionette/content/element.js:330:16\n' }
finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the incorrect element. Instead of selecting `#i0118`, the correct element. I STUPIDLY selected `#i0116`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to wait for a action to be completed you can try sleep from

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit:
```

if u want it in seconds u can use

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(int);
```

and for minutes you can use

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(int);
```

The raw way to use sleep would be to use Thread.sleep() but the input here should be in milliseconds of if your program contains multiple sleep statements i would prefer TimeUnit

Comment: I thank you for help, but the question is directed at javascript/nodejs